# Setting values of Java enumerated types

Tags: java, enums

I would like to use `enums` to group constant variables in my small program and I would like to set the values so that I can extract the values later and use them as integers.

I am thinking of something like this:

```
public enum Value {
    THREE = 3,
    SIX = 6, 
    NINE = 9
}
```

So later I can retrive the value for something like this:

```
int[] myIntArray = new int[Value.THREE];
```

I previously used `C++` this way but this does not work for me in Java. Is there a way of explicitly setting a Java enumerated value and can someone explain how I would set and then extract the value from my `enum`?

Comment: You can do this, but there's no point.  Just use three constants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of Java is as follows:

```
public enum NUMBER
{
    THREE(3),
    SIX(6), 
    NINE(9);

    NUMBER(int value){this.value = value;}

    private int value;

    public int getValue(){return value;}
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
int[] myIntArray = new int[NUMBER.THREE.getValue()];
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say that's not the logically correct way of using `ENUMs`. Enums are not of any specific java types (like `int` `float` etc). **They are types themselves**.  For example, say to define bank account types,

```
public enum AccountTYpe
{
    SAVING(1),
    CHECKING(2);
```

}

Now the **advantage of using enum** is that for a variable of type `AccountTYpe` there are only two valid assignments namely the `SAVING` and `CHECKING`. Anything else would flag a compile error.

Your requirement seems to be **integer constants** for which I would suggest to use set of values defined inside an interface as follows

```
public interface Value {
    Integer THREE = 3;
    Integer SIX = 6;
    Integer NINE = 9;
}
```

Since the variables defined inside the interface are `public` `static` and `final` you can use them as constants in your code as desired.

```
int[] myIntArray = new int[Value.THREE];
```

Comment: I think that use of Interfaces is a bit of an anti-pattern. It rather defeats the idea of an interface being a functionality contract...

Comment: But you can achieve the same thing with either a class or an interface.  It doesn't matter which you choose.  Many people do prefer classes for this.  This is clearly the best of the three answers that are currently here.

Answer (score 0):

Use a constructor

```
public enum Value {
    THREE(3), SIX(6), NINE(9);

    private int value;

    private Value(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```